# Why people generate the JWTs with the same secret?

Tags: jwt

I read some JWT tutorials, but **they didn't talk about how to generate a random secret**.

So I generate the JWT with a secret then I generate another JWT with the same secret? **What if somebody already knew what my secret is**?

Isn't that means that **he can fake, or modify the information** and sign the JWT on his own then send it to my server?

To deal with the problem, I want to encrypt the JWT with a random, unique secret (and store the random secret to my database, left an index of the secret behind of the encrypted string), but **should I**? **Is there anything I overthinking of**?

Comment: Well... that's why it's called a secret. It is not supposed to be revealed to third parties. If you suspect your secret is leaked, generate a new one. Your site should just use a single secret, stored in a configuration file (like `config.ini`), which should not be accessible—e.g. by placing it outside the web directory.

Comment: Why didn't I use the random secret for each user so it will only affect on an user if it's leaked ..?

Comment: The thing with JWT is to avoid making any database transactions. Using a MySQL database to store keys defeats the intended purpose of JWT. JWT has to be encoded using SHA2-256, which will take a lot of time to crack anyway—right now it is still computationally too expensive to extract the secret from a JWT.

Comment: JWT is not crypted with the secret. It is just base64 encoded data. Secret is used for signing the token.

Comment: @MikaTuupola Not always true, JWTs can be both signed (JWS) or not signed, encrypted (JWE) or non encrypted or a combination of both.

Comment: @Terry JWTs only have to be _encoded_ with "base64-url" encoding. Above that it may be _signed_ (with for example SHA-256) and/or _encrypted_.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not sign each JWT with a unique secret and store the secrets in your database. If you are afraid that your secret will leak and want to solve that issue with a database lookup for each incoming call, you should use regular random generated tokens and then lookup the "claims" for that token for each request in your database, (or use a regular season pattern).

So instead of using a databases to verify the information in the JWT for each call, store the information that you planed to store in the JWT in the database instead.